# nodemailer -issue with connection

Tags: nodemailer

> { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:587
>       at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
>       at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
>       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1182:14)   code: 'ECONNECTION',   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',   syscall: 'connect',
>   address: '127.0.0.1',   port: 587,   command: 'CONN' }

```
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        auth: {
            user: 'email',
            pass: 'password '
        }
    });
```

I've switched on https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps . What can it be ? I've tried ports - 465,25,463 ...it also isn't working . What should I do ?

Comment: Whats the cloud you're using ?

Comment: What do you mean(cloud)?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this transporter.
Be sure to install Oauth2 using `npm install oauth2`and then requiring it in the file by using `const Oauth2 = require('oauth2');`

You can get the clientid, clientsecret, refreshtoken(be sure to set autorefresh on) and accestoken at https://console.developers.google.com/ and https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ this is for the gmail api.

```
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'Gmail',
  auth: {
  type: 'OAuth2',
  user: 'yourmail',
  clientId: 'yourclientid',
  clientSecret: 'yourclientsecret',
  refreshToken: 'yourrefreshtoken',
  accessToken: 'youraccestoken',
  },
  });
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, how do you get the: clientid, clientsecret, refreshtoken(be sure to set autorefresh on) and accestoken at the developer console? the account used to login to gmail services should be the same as the user ("yourclientid")? also about the token, that should be the oauth2 token, or the gmail api token?

Comment: you get the clientid, clientsecret, refreshtoken and acces token at: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
You then click on the gear, check use your own OAuth credentials paste your ID and SECRET you got here. Then you input the gmail api as scope (I forgot the link I used for this but if the link ends with a '/' it can give you a error so be sure to remove the '/' at the end. When you've done this click on "Exchange authorization code for tokens" once you've done this you will get the two tokens, click auto refresh on so you won't need to do it manually and copy paste the codes.

Comment: I haven't done this in a while and the https://console.developers.google.com/ has changed a bit since I've last configured my projects. But I think I can still figure it out and send you a more detailed guide to getting the keys and tokens, if you'd like.

Comment: I'm also having this issue, adding the `oauth2` package doesn't seem to help